# Why is the [^] sscanf specifier breaking my program? (C)

Tags: c, string, debugging, scanf, stdio

I'm trying to analyze a bunch of strings with sscanf in c;

The strings are formatted like this: (float) (name) (float)

```
example: 
-26.73 Sun 0.000016 
-0.27 Alpha Centauri    4.4
```

so I've set up my code like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define WORD 50
#define PHRASE 150

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
    char frase [PHRASE+1]= "";
    char star[WORD+1]= "";
    char mom [WORD+1]= "";
    float meg=0, dist=0;
    int ins=0;
    
    FILE *fp;
    
    fp = fopen("stelle.txt", "r");

    if (argc==1){
    }
    
    sscanf(argv[1], "%[1234567890]", mom);
    ins=atoi(mom);
    
        while (fgets(frase, PHRASE, fp)){
            sscanf(frase, "%f %[^ 1234567890] %f", &meg, star, &dist);
            if (ins==0){
                if ((strcmp(argv[1],star))==0)
                    printf("%g %g", meg, dist);
            }
            
            else {
                if (ins>dist)
                    printf("%g %s\n", meg, star);
            }
        }
    
    return 0;
    }
```

This works! but sometimes the name can be made up of two words, and %s can only really see the first word, so I should use the [^] specifier.
so I write:

```
    sscanf(phrase, "%f %[^1234567890] %f", &meg, star, &dist)
```

and this code literally breaks the program and makes it crash, and I can't really tell why, but if I write %[^ 1234567890] it's working again, but this doesn't really solve my problem, so what is going on here? where's the issue?

Comment: `sscanf` is a bit of a crutch. Why not scan for the first space with [`strchr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr), and the last with [`strrchr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strrchr), then the remainder is considered the name?

Comment: Did you check the return code from `sscanf` before using the results? If not they might be mangled and using them could cause a crash.

Comment: It would help if you had a *complete, syntactically valid* example here. This is missing a lot.

Comment: The `%[^]` specifier is going to include the trailing space(s) in the string. If that causes your program to crash, then there' something wrong in the code you haven't shown. See [mcve].

Comment: this is for a university assignment and I'm limited with which functions I can work with, so strchr and strrchr are not an option I can make use of.

Comment: where are you opening file? that might be your issue.

Comment: I've posted the complete code; what I posted here before was a minimal reproducible example or at least the one that I used to study what was going on, but after re-doing it for the second time, the [^] works correctly, so the issue must be from somewhere else in the code.

Comment: One problem is that you are using `argv[1]` without checking `argc` first. The `sscanf(argv[1], ..., &mom);` will crash and burn unless `argc` is at least 2. The following `atoi` should not be called if the `sscanf` fails. And the `if (argc==1) { }` later in the code does nothing because there's nothing between the opening and closing braces. Note that `argc` needs to be at least 2 if you want the `strcmp(argv[1], ...)` to work.

Comment: @tadman "Did you check the return code from sscanf?" => I'm ready to bet that 95% of the issues here about scanf() are due to the programmer not checking its return value.

Comment: What do you mean by crash?

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of what appears to be diagnostic code and other debugging debris that is interfering with the operation of your program. I've cleaned it up here:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define WORD 50
#define PHRASE 150

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  FILE *fp = fopen("stelle.txt", "r");

  if (!fp) {
    // Referencing a NULL pointer later on will result in an immediate crash
    // so this error indicates trouble and exits.
    printf("Could not open file\n");

    return -1;
  }

  char line[PHRASE+1];
  while (fgets(line, PHRASE, fp)) {
    char star[WORD+1];
    float meg;
    float dist;

    int srv = sscanf(line, "%f %[^1234567890] %f", &meg, star, &dist);

    if (srv == 3) {
      printf("%g '%s' %g\n", meg, star, dist);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

This works for me on the input you've given.